# Sequelize bulk synchronization does nothing

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm unable to get [sequelize.sync()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#database-synchronization) to work. Calling `sync()` on each model definition works flawlessly but calling it from the sequelize instance appears do to nothing, like if the model manager had no registered models in it.

Consider the following:

```
function syncAll() {
    console.log('Retrieving exported models...')
    let models = require('./models')
    for(var modelName in models) {
        let model = models[modelName]
        // define() just wraps a regular sequelize.define() call
        // model.define().sync() works!
        model.define()
    }

    console.log('All exported models have been defined! Syncing database...')
    sequelize.sync({
        logging: true
    }).then(function() {
        // The operation completes but no command is executed in the DB
        console.log('Database synchronization complete!')
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Database synchronization error:\n\t${error}")
    })
}
```

Just trying to understand what I'm missing, why bulk synchronization isn't working for me?

AFAIK I just need all models defined before calling `sequelize.sync()`, right?!

#### EDIT 1

Some info about my environment: I'm using node 5.6 under debian with postgres

#### EDIT 2

Found the problem. Refer to end of the accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code from sequelize [example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) works fine for me:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db: any = {};

var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
  title: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Task.belongsTo(models.User, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

var User = sequelize.define("User", {
  username: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Task);
    }
  }
});

db.User = User;
db.Task = Task;

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  // some code here
});
```

Models have been defined via "sequelize.define(...)" and after that "sequelize.sync()" has been called.

#### Update 1

I'm using sqlite:

```
var config: any = {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "./db.development.sqlite"
};
```

#### Update from OP

I've spotted the only diference between this code and mine. Due to a bug in my logic `sequelize.define()` and `sequelize.sync()` were being called from different sequelize instances (i.e different connections) and each connection has its own `modelManager` so obviously there was no models to sync in the second connection object.

Comment: What did you used for your test?! I'm using postgres. I'll test your code when I get home, thank you...

Comment: I'm using sqlite (Update 1).